# ASP.NET Core Keycloak authentication - access token expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, keycloak

I'm trying to setup a simple authentication process in web api using Keycloak as identity provider. And almost everything works as expected. When client is trying to reach protected route, the keycloak login popup shows up, user logs in and both asp.net and keycloak cookies are being stored.

[Stored cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLxHW.png)

In realm settings I specified access token lifespan to 30 seconds.

[Access token lifespan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSzbK.png)

For test purposes when I deleted the Keycloak cookies and left only the ones created by web api my protected route is still accessible. But the problem is that it is accessible even if access token already expired (30 seconds passed). Can you explain to me why it works that way?

Here's authentication part of code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/testrealm";
    options.ClientId = "testclient";
    options.ClientSecret = "kUOYGYajzgic9Feuw5rE5WRQLtgXuNTm";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
        RoleClaimType = "roles",
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

I've tried changing the clockskew, signing user out from realm sessions panel, but protected route was still accessible.

Comment: Because you asked for that. The `DefaultScheme` is checked first which allows all cookie authenticated requests. If not logged in `DefaultChallengeScheme` will trigger the oauth login, and set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might happened because Keycloak and aspnet core’s conflict. for my test result , the authentication state can be maintained by keycloak session and aspnet cookie at the same time so if you clear all of cookie in your  browser , or delete cookie generated by aspnet after you clear your session in keycloak.  you should need to log in again.